# MySQL - Use MAX() on one column and also return data from the rest of the row?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, max

I'm not sure if this is a complicated issue or if I'm just missing something trivial, but I can't quite figure this out.

I have a table that lists error messages and the time they appeared:

```
id     created_at          content
1      2017-08-05 08:00    ...
2      2017-08-15 16:00    ...
3      2017-08-15 16:01    ...
4      2017-08-15 16:02    ...
5      2017-08-25 16:00    ...
```

I group these rows together based on date and hour and count how many errors appeared:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m. %h'), 
       COUNT(*) AS errorCount 
       FROM db.errorData 
       GROUP BY DAY(created_at), HOUR(created_at);
```

Resulting in this:

```
created_at          errorCount
2017-08-05 08       1
2017-08-15 16       3
2017-08-25 16       1
```

Now I want to use `MAX()` to get the highest errorCount. I do this with a subselect:

```
SELECT MAX(errorCount) AS errorMax 
       FROM(
         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m. %h'), 
         COUNT(*) AS errorCount 
         FROM db.errorData 
         GROUP BY DAY(created_at), HOUR(created_at)
       ) alias;
```

However, I also want to get the date of the day with the most errors. Simply adding `created_at` to the first SELECT doesn't work since it only returns the value of the first row.

I don't know how to make this work right now. Can you help me out?

Comment: if there exists more than a day with most errors, then how do you want the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ORDER BY` clause and `LIMIT` the count of records will fetch your desired result.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m. %h') AS created_at, 
       COUNT(*) AS errorCount 
  FROM db.errorData 
 GROUP BY DAY(created_at), HOUR(created_at)
 ORDER BY errorCount DESC, created_at ASC
 LIMIT 1;
```

And if there are many days with the same errorCount, you have to take a decision to pick a specific day.

My above solution just picks the oldest day with max errors.

Comment: I guess I was too focused on using `MAX()` that I didn't think of ordering the data instead. In my case, getting the newest day is ideal. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: @Magnar: for the newest day, just use `DESC` in lieu of `ASC` in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `limit 1` to the end of the query and order it regarding the errors count

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m. %h'), 
  COUNT(*) AS errorCount 
FROM db.errorData 
  GROUP BY DAY(created_at), HOUR(created_at)
  ORDER BY errorCount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT (created_at, '%d.%m. %h'), 
          count(*) as errorCount
from
db.errordata
groupby day(created_at)
HAVING errorCount>= ALL (
 SELECT    
 COUNT(*) AS errorCount 
 FROM db.errorData 
 GROUP BY DAY(created_at), HOUR(created_at)
)
```

I hope this may help you.